# IOException thrown by AccountManagerFuture.getResults whereas connection is alive

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, access-token, google-account

The following method systematically throws a IOException when invoked on my Android device whereas the internet connection is alive (I can retrieve emails or connect to gmail using my Android device).

Can anyone please help?

```
private void performAuthentication() {
    Log.d("GAWidget", "performAuthentication");
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential();
    GoogleAccountManager accountManager = new GoogleAccountManager(this);
    Log.d("GAWidget", "after getting accountManager");
    Account account = accountManager.getAccountByName("balteo@gmail.com");
    Log.d("GAWidget", "after getting account"+"account.name: "+account.name);
    accountManager.getAccountManager().getAuthToken(account, "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/‌​analytics.readonly",
            true, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                    try {
                        String token = future.getResult(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS).getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                        Log.d("GAWidget", "token: "+token);
                        useToken(token);
                    } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                        Log.e("GAWidget", "OperationCanceledException", e);
                    } catch (AuthenticatorException e) {
                        Log.e("GAWidget", "AuthenticatorException", e);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("GAWidget", "IOException", e);
                    }
                }

            }, null);
}
```

Edit: Here is the stack trace:

```
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487): IOException
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487): java.io.IOException
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487):  at android.accounts.AccountManager.convertErrorToException(AccountManager.java:1440)
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487):  at android.accounts.AccountManager.access$400(AccountManager.java:138)
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487):  at android.accounts.AccountManager$AmsTask$Response.onError(AccountManager.java:1301)
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487):  at android.accounts.IAccountManagerResponse$Stub.onTransact(IAccountManagerResponse.java:69)
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
05-27 19:09:04.319: E/GAWidget(12487):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

shipped jars:

```
google-http-client-1.9.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-android2-1.9.0-beta.jar (only for SDK >= 2.1)
google-http-client-android3-1.9.0-beta.jar (only for SDK >= 3.0)
gson-2.1.jar
guava-11.0.1.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
```

Answer (score 7):

The `AccountManager` is converting any network errors into `IOException`'s. A network error could be some sort of unexpected HTTP status, so it might not be directly related to network connectivity. Note that the `AccountManager` supports some, but not all 'oauth2:' type tokens, so that might be related. Try with a token that is known to be supported. Also look at the logcat for hints, there might be some warnings there. Is this the full stack trace?

This works on a GN 4.0.4 (note it is using the system `AccountManager`, not `GoogleAccountManager`):

```
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
    String AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";
    am.getAuthToken(accounts[0], AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, null,
                   this, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                           try {
                             String token = 
future.getResult().getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                            System.out.println("token " + token);
                            } catch (...) {}

                            }
                        }, null);
```

Edit: Here's what I get when copying the token type from your post:

```
0000000: 226f 6175 7468 323a 6874 7470 733a 2f2f  "oauth2:https://
0000010: 7777 772e 676f 6f67 6c65 6170 6973 2e63  www.googleapis.c
0000020: 6f6d 2f61 7574 682f 3f3f 616e 616c 7974  om/auth/??analyt
0000030: 6963 732e 7265 6164 6f6e 6c79 220a       ics.readonly".
```

Again, this might be my browser or smth, by check your string (esp. last part)

Comment: BTW, this works fine on my Galaxy Nexus (4.0.4), but you seem to have some strange characters in your token type. Might be just a copy-paste error, but re-type the string and make sure it's ASCII only just in case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nikolay, I tried to remove the "oauth2:" part in the url and I get a null token. Can you please elaborate on the strange characters in the token type? I don't see what you mean. Regarding the warnings I also get this: "GoogleLoginService: status 200 but response didn't include auth token". Any idea?

Comment: I also sometimes get the following warning: "IInputConnectionWrapper showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection"

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly how you managed to get it to work with your Nexus? Especially how what did you change in the code in order to get it to work sucessfully?

Comment: Ohh, I see now. I am using the system AccountManager, not `GoogleAccountManager`. See updated post (again).

Comment: I tried using the AccountManager as you advised...to no avail. I get the very same IOException as before... There is one thing I am unsure about: do I need the "oauth2" part?

Comment: OK, GoogleAcountManager is a very thin wrapper around the system one, so it really doesn't matter which one you use. Yes, you do need the "oauth2:" part, that's what tells the AccoutManager to get an OAuth2 token. On what device are you trying this? The actual code that deals with Google tokens is in the Google services libraries, so depending on their version, it may or may not work properly. The ones one a GN are presumably the more (most?) recent ones.

Comment: I am using version google-api-java-client-1.9.0-beta downloaded from google code...

Comment: Device: samsung galaxy ace S5830

Comment: Try it with another device if you have the chance. the google-api-java-client version doesn't really matter here, since you are calling Android system code here.

Comment: Do you mean I should not include/ship the jars listed above in the libs directory?

Comment: No. I mean, you cannot control how the Google accounts implementation of AccountManager works. If it's broken you can't fix it. Only an Android software update might. You can always get a token using a WebView, etc. as described here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps though. You don't necessarily have to use the AccountManager.

Comment: I am pretty sure I must be making some basic mistake rather than Google code being broken... Unfortunately I don't have another device on which to test my app..... :-(

Comment: Even Google code is not always bug-free :) There is nothing wrong with your code, as far as I can see. Use a WebView and you can be pretty sure it will work on almost all devices. AccountManager OAuth2 support is far from reliable on all Android versions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I filed a bug report and will post here according to the reply I get.